# I need to get sum of numbers present in a string java android

Tags: java, android, sum, logic

Input String s = "100.0 + 50.0 + 20.0"

required Output Sum = 170.0

I tried multiple conversions and datatypes but not working as expected, even check stack overflow and other sites but still not really sure how to do this.
I tried multiple conversions and datatypes but not working as expected, even check stack overflow and other sites but still not really sure how to do this.

Comment: Conversions and data types won't solve this.  What you are trying to do is *evaluate an expression* represented by a string.  There is no builtin support in Java SE for that.  So you either need to find a 3rd-party expression evaluator (capable of understanding your expression language) or write one yourself.  The latter may be simple ... or complicated ... depending on your "language".  (The single example you have shown would be simple. But we can generalize from a single example to the entire language that you envisage.)

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the String into smaller strings and then process.

```
String input = "100.0 + 50.0 + 20.0";
String[] parts = input.split(" "); // split where there is a space
```

The result of the splitting will be

```
[100.0 , + , 50.0 , + , 20.0]
```

Now, you can process the numbers and ignore the '+' sign.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for(String s : numbers){
     if(s.equals("+") || s.isEmpty())
         continue; // ignore spaces and + sign
     double number = Double.parseDouble(s);   // convert others to double
     sum += number;  // calculate the sum
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

NOTE : This approach will not work if there isn't space between numbers in your input i.e. if input is like "150+70+20" this will not work. This is very basic approach, if you have complex use cases, better to use some library.